# IndexError: list index out of range ( Help fix please)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am pretty new at python and was looking for a little help with a problem i'm  having. I have a program that is required to refresh and grab times and use it for something. Here is the code for finding the time :

```
def findNST(html):
    NST = re.findall(r'<td id="nst">(.*) am', html)
    if NST == []:
        NST = re.findall(r'<td id="nst">(.*) pm', html)
    p = re.compile('\d+')
    Times = p.findall(NST[0])
    return NST, Times
```

The issue im having is that sometimes when it refreshes. Its either getting and error page or a blank page and then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Bot folder\frankie\client.py", line 166, in <module>
Times = find_firstrs()
File "C:\Python27\Bot folder\frankie\client.py", line 81, in find_firstrs
NST, Times = findNST(html)
File "C:\Python27\Bot folder\frankie\client.py", line 50, in findNST
Times = p.findall(NST[0])
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can somebody please help me fix this.

Comment: Why don't you `print NST`?

Comment: I do thats later on in the code. If you want I can post the whole code.

Comment: No, I mean to find out why you get an `IndexError`.

Comment: Well I know whats causing the erorr. Its when it refrshesing its not getting the time its either getting a blank page or an error page that doesnt display the time for it to get.

Comment: So what's the problem? Sometimes both lists will be empty, evidently you know how to check if a list is empty, you just have to decide what you want to `return` (or `raise`) in that case.

Comment: Im sorry but this isnt my program. Im really new to python. I just needed help fixing this one problem.

Comment: Then you should spend some time learning the language and figure how that (relatively simple) code works; once you understand it, it will be easy for you to modify it appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

`IndexError: list index out of range` means `NST` is an empty list, which from your code indicates that none of the regexes are matching in the `html`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). Well it does match it for a little. I should have been more specific. After running it for a while it will randomly crash because at some random point either 20-30 min in its gettin an error page saying the page is down because the server goes down for a sec or a blank page. Either way what im looking for is a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix is to check NST before actually trying to access it:

```
if NST: # check we have data before indexing
    Times = p.findall(NST[0])
```

Judging by the code provided I would find better code to learn from, variable names should be lowercase and function names use underscores:

```
def find_nst(html):
    nst = re.findall(r'<td id="nst">(.*) am', html)
    if not nst: # same as if ast == []
        nst = re.findall(r'<td id="nst">(.*) pm', html)
    p = re.compile('\d+')
    if nst: # if nst is not empty
        times = p.findall(nst[0])
    else:
        times = []
    return nst, times
```

Depending on what other parts of your code do with the return values, you may want to return a different default value for times.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have run into another error. Im looking to pay someone to fix this thing "if its allowed" so if anyone if interested shoot me a pm.